# Finding the sum,highest,lowest in a Hash/Array. Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am fairly new to this so I apologize in advance of my newbieness. I have been working on a project that I want to get the sum, highest,lowest out of a hash/array. I have tried numerous times to get this right but I typically will get an error such as, fixNum cannot convert int to string and undefined method. I will attempt to fix these issues and then run into another issue so I am at a loss. For the record in my text file I have `1,Foo,22 2,Smith,30` my output looks like this `{1=>["Foo",22], 2=>["Smith",30]}` I would like the highest number to show 30, lowest to be 22 and total to be 52 for different outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to hash and calculate min max based on values

```
data = "1,Foo,22 2,Smith,30"
people = 
    data.split(",")
        .each_slice(3)
        .map {|slice| [slice[0], [slice[1], slice[2]]] }
        .to_h

values = people.values.map {|person| person[1] }
min = values.min
max = values.max
sum = values.sum
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below suppose lets say a variable `a = {a: [a,1],b: [b,1] }` then

```
values = a.values.map(&:last) //Gives the last element of each array
max= a.max
min = a.min
sum = a.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is very ugly and someone will probably improve upon it but it works. Assuming I understand the output you would like.

```
elements = h.map{ |element| element[1] }.map { |element| element[1]}

# sum 
elements.sum

# highest
elements.max

# lowest
elements.min
```

https://repl.it/repls/AntiqueOldfashionedRom

Comment: ...or replace the last two with `elements.minmax`.